# Exclude column from being read using pd.ExcelFile().parse()

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I would like to exclude certain columns from being read when using pd.ExcelFile('my.xls').parse()

Excel file I am trying to parse has too many columns to list them all in usecols argument since I only need to get rid off a single column that is causing trouble.

Is there like a simple way to ~ invert list (I know you can't do that) passed to usecols or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can usually do

```
head = list(pd.read_csv('your.xls', nrows = 1))

df = pd.read_excel('your.xls', usecols = [col for col in head if col != 'the one drop']))
```

However , why not read whole file then `drop` it

```
df = pd.read_excel('your.xls').drop('the col drop', axis = 1)
```

Comment: I can't read and then drop because data type is inconsistent in that column and it causes interpreter to crash. Thanks for your input, I've solved it doing the this:

            for sheet in sheets:
                cols = list(excel.parse(sheet_name=sheet, header=0))

                if 'bad_col' in cols:
                    cols.remove('bad_col')

                df = excel.parse(
                        sheet_name=sheet,
                        usecols=cols
                )

Comment: Actually nevermind, I can read file and then drop it, it was crushing during compiling into another file and not when being read. I just had to make sure to check if its present first, due to header inconsistency across sheets.